# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect error occurs when trying to bind the data and send to controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-form

Im trying to bind data from a jsp form and send it to the controller in order to persist.

the form :

```
        <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user" action="adduser">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role-name" class="col-form-label">User Name</label>
                <form:input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="role-name" path="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role-name" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
                <form:input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="name" path="name" />
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="role">Role</label>
                    <form:select class="form-control"
                            required="required"  path="role" id="role">
                        <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="role">
                            <form:option value="${role}" label="${role.roleName}" />
                        </c:forEach>
                    </form:select>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="state">Status</label>
                <form:select class="form-control" id="state"
                        required="required"  path="state" >
                    <form:option value="ACTIVE" label="ACTIVE" />
                    <form:option value="INACTIVE" label="INACTIVE" />
                </form:select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role-name" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
                <form:input type="password" required="required" class="form-control" id="password" path="password" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form:form>
```

the controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") SystemUser user, ModelMap model) {

    userService.saveSystemUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("user", new SystemUser());
    return new ModelAndView("users");
}
```

the model :

```
@Entity(name = "system_user")
public class SystemUser implements Serializable {

public enum State {ACTIVE, INACTIVE}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
private String username;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "state")
private State state;
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private SystemRole role;
}
```

but i keep getting the
      "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" error on the browser and  `nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'SystemRole' for property 'role': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]` on the log. In here i send the whole role object as well. but i keep getting these two errors when i try to do this. what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the error logs it is clear that spring is not able to convert to Role entity object.

Define a central class for all the conversations and converters like below.

```
@Configurable
/**
 * A central place to register application converters and formatters. 
 */
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void installFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.installFormatters(registry);
    }

    public Converter<Role, String> getRoleToStringConverter() {
        return new Converter<com.package.Role, String>() {
            @Override
            public String convert(Role role) {
                return new StringBuilder().append(role.getRoleName()).toString();
            }
        };
    }

    public Converter<Long, Role> getIdToRoleConverter() {
        return new Converter<Long, com.package.Role>() {
            @Override
            public com.package.Role convert(Long id) {
                return roleService.read(id);
            }
        };
    }

    public Converter<String, Role> getStringToRoleConverter() {
        return new Converter<String, com.package.Role>() {
            @Override
            public com.package.Role convert(String id) {
                return getObject().convert(getObject().convert(id, Long.class), Role.class);
            }
        };
    }


    public void installLabelConverters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

        registry.addConverter(getRoleToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(getIdToRoleConverter());
        registry.addConverter(getStringToRoleConverter());

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        installLabelConverters(getObject());
    }
}
```

But to make spring aware of this class you need to inject the below bean in in configuration applicationContext.xml.

```
<bean class="com.package.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService"/>
```

and register the service class in configuration applicationContext.xml like below.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/>
```